# Linux find utility cannot see fstype of nfs partition

Tags: linux, debian, nfs, find

I have 2 debian linux servers that are pretty similar, and mount the same set of nfs partitions.  Investigating a problem with **find** not ignoring nfs partitions when rebuilding the **locate** db, I found that find cannot tell when it is on an nfs partition, on web7, but has no problem on web8.

```
web7-debian-6.0.10-#  df -TP /usr/dir/mediaroot
 Filesystem    Type 1024-blocks      Used Available Capacity Mounted on
 nas1:/volume2/mediaroot nfs 11527817528 5013498232 6514216896      44% /usr/dir/mediaroot
web7-debian-6.0.10-#  find /usr/dir -maxdepth 1 -printf "%F %h/%f\n" | grep media
 none /usr/dir/mediaroot

web8-debian-6.0.5-#  df -TP /usr/dir/mediaroot
 Filesystem    Type 1024-blocks      Used Available Capacity Mounted on
 nas1:/volume2/mediaroot nfs 11527817528 5013538392 6514176736      44% /usr/dir/mediaroot
web8-debian-6.0.5-#  find /usr/dir -maxdepth 1 -printf "%F %h/%f\n" | grep media
 nfs /usr/dir/mediaroot
```

No other utility on web7 seems to have any problem seeing the type of partition.  While I can configure the locate db rebuild process to ignore "none" file systems, it would be nice to fix the none-vs.-nfs problem.  oldfind has the same problem.  Both hosts have the same and latest version of findutils for the OS.  The erroring system was rebooted 7 days ago and the problem started showing up 27 days ago.  Oddly, one nfs partition on web7 does show up as nfs in the find commnd.   One other server, debian 6.0.9, also has this problem.  I have other debian 6.0.10 servers that do not have this problem.

I am trying to find out where **find** gets its fstype information, no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are talking about `find` or `locate`?

Bit I guess locate / mlocate, where the update command is `updatedb`.

The settings are here: `/etc/updatedb.conf`

Looks like:

```
PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="yes"
# PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn"
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media /data/cache /data/docker"
PRUNEFS="NFS nfs nfs4 rpc_pipefs afs binfmt_misc proc smbfs autofs iso9660 ncpfs coda devpts ftpfs devfs mfs shfs sysfs cifs lustre tmpfs usbfs udf fuse.glusterfs fuse.sshfs curlftpfs"
```